# Click method not responding Jamboard

Tags: javascript, click

I am trying to write an extension for Jamboard and have been messing with it in the console. I have noticed that after calling the click() method on the arrow element that is supposed to change slides (id: ":h"), it does not do anything. Any ideas?

```
document.getElementById(':h').click()
```

Comment: Try document.getElementById(':h').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));

Comment: It still doesn't change the slide